# Can we deploy sharepoint workflow (made in sharepoint designer) as feature

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-deployment

I am newbie to Sharepoint.

I want to create workflow as template using Sharepoint designer and deploy it as feature.

Following link [Workflow Deployment Using Features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms414556.aspx) suggests, this can be achieved in visual studio.

I have following questions
1. Can sharepoint foundation has workflow as template
2. Can we deploy workflow made in designer as feature

If answer to both these is yes, please share some links to get started for these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Reusable workflow for this. 
Assuming you are on SharePoint 2010,

1. Create a new reusable workflow.
2. Save it and publish it and test that it works fine
3. In the ribbon, use Save as Template option to save it.

It will get saved in Site Assets Library as wsp form where you can download it and upload to other sites as wsp and activate the feature to use it there.

More information can be found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231580.aspx

Comment: I understand the steps. Question is can workflow be deployed as feature (not as WSP)?

Comment: Feature can not be deployed directly to SharePoint. You create feature and then bundle it in a wsp to deploy to the SharePoint environment. One the WSP is activated, it installs the feature and then you can activate it. Please let me know if I am missing anything...

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I have done exactly the way you have described, and it has worked as expected.